# :after css is creating issues

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've been facing a problem - I need to make a category page for an e-commerce website. The client's required design depicts that they need to get a horizontal line *after* the category title (which is dynamic).

I've done it to this part.

However, the issue arises when the client needs to change the category name. In the attached picture, it says "Category 2". Client may change it to 'Men's Collection', 'Winter Collection', 'Men' or whatever.

The problem is, since we don't know about the width that this category name is going to occupy, how can I manage the horizontal line's width (highlighted in a red box).

I'm also putting a screenshot of the css that I've applied.

The position of the line being absolute, width does need to be managed.

How can I manage this width? :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a `flexbox` to solve the issue- see the example below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="wrapper">
  category name
</h1>
```

Comment: Do note that I also need to manage the "Sort By" button there! I'm not sure if this is going to work well there too...

Comment: @r0nn13 give a similar flexbox to the wrapper that includes this and the sort by section...

Answer (score 0):

IDK why is my question demoted.

However, I've done a little thing that will work fine =>

1. For the "Sort By" section, I've made the background color white.
2. For the whole row containing the category, :after line and Sort By section, I've hidden the overflow.

That's working fine, however I'ld have appreciated only if I could get some other approach to work.

Comment: Your question is "demoted" because questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]

Comment: I've included the desired behaviour, specific problem, and even the code too. I believe my question was clear too. Well, nevermind. I've learnt something from here, so I guess it's not a big deal. :)

Comment: You need to include actual code - not a picture of it

Answer (score 0):

Well it should be dynamic if you specify the width of the :after element as a percentage. Since it is getting the width of the parent (which is the title), the width will adjust on the percentage amount of whatever the title is.